# Overwriting line in unix shell after printing

Tags: shell, ksh, printf

How can I modify a line after printing it in unix shell.We can delete the line and write again by using `\r` as shown below,but how can I overwrite on existing line and not delete it completely and get the output as in Expected output below.

**Command:**

```
printf "12345";printf "\r67";
```

**Output:**

```
67
```

**Expected Output**

```
67345
```

Comment: `printf "12345";printf "\r67\n"` does the job on my terminal. I am however unable to account for it

Comment: @1_CR is correct.  You are missing `\n`.

Comment: @1_CR Without that newline, the cursor is left after the 7.  What g4ur4v did *not* post in his/her output is the command prompt (eg, `67>`) which overwrote the 345.  With the newline, the cursor will move to the next line instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem is where you've left the cursor.  For example:

```
goldilocks@home> echo -n 1234; echo -ne "\r56"
56goldilocks@home>
```

What happened is the first `echo` wrote "1234", then the second echo went back to the beginning of the line and printed "56" and exited.  The cursor remained after the 6, and the next thing that happened is the shell printed the command prompt, overwriting "34".  If you included a newline in the second echo (or removed the `-n` switch, so that echo will print a newline automatically), you would get:

```
goldilocks@home> echo -n 1234; echo -e "\r56"
5634
goldilocks@home>
```

The cursor moved down a line, leaving the "34" behind.

Comment: Is your username even goldilocks? Too funny.

Comment: @slm : Actually it's `Freakin_Finnickity_Goldilocks_the_Magnificent` but I edit these things for brevity ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a little advanced sed expression

```
printf '%s\n' {1..5} | sed '/1/,/2/{ s/1/6/;s/2/7/;s/\([^\n]*\)\(\n\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/; }' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Using `awk`

```
printf '%s' {1..5} | awk '{gsub(/12/,"67"); print}'
```

Using `tr`

```
printf '%s' {1..5} | tr '12' '67'
```

Comment: In the question I asked for overwriting a line that is already printed on shell .But your answer is about passing output of one to another and then printing on the shell,this is not I was looking for.Anyways ,Thanks for answering.

Comment: @g4ur4v at both first examples I'm overriding the `printf` built-in. In your example you are using a carriage return `\r` which overrides `printf`s output. Take this example  `echo "12345"; printf '\r67\n'`

Comment: What I wanted to stress on your examples is the use of `|` instead of `;` .As per my understanding `;` between two commands is like running two commands next to next and both the commands being independent of each other.But in your example, you are redirecting output of one to another.